# Unable to Load Excel File into Google Data Fusion from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am not able to load excel file from google cloud storage to data fusion center neither by using the data source option as a excel nor using wrangler.
while using wrangler to load data it says non displayable object.

Could you please help me with detailed explanation of how to load excel file into data fusion center

Answer (score 2):

You can read excel files in wrangler. Steps to reproduce,

1. Go to wranger connections (`<cdap-host>:<cdap-port>/cdap/ns/default/connections`)
2. Create a connection to GCS.
3. Once connection created, browse through the connection and select the file
4. Once you select the file you will then be taken to wrangler tab which will display "Non displayable object"
5. You can now open the dropdown on the column and select Parse -> Excel.[image]
6. Once you the Excel option wrangler should walk you through a step to choose your sheet number or name to parse.

After step 6 you should now be able to see your excel data in wrangler like this,
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: .Thanks for the detailed explanation. I tried this - It gives an error  'Java Heap Space' . Could you please help me to resolve this error

Comment: @ChiragDadheech is there a sequence of steps you are doing (Is it exactly as mentioned in the answer)? Is it possible to share a sample excel document that you are trying (stripping all sensitive information)? Do you know how big is the excel file you are trying to wrangle?

Comment: I am following the exact steps as mentioned above. It is simple excel file (around 1 MB)